# How do I migrate to a existing taxonomy reference field?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8, migrations

Given a source that has a field with the corresponding ID which outputs the id in the field `special` like the field `nid` gives back a node id.

I want to map it to a taxonomy term that is already existing on the new site and not migrated.

This is the process part of my custom yml file:

```
process:
  nid: nid
  vid: vid
  # there were some more fields here that I left out.
  # hardcode destination node type as publication
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: publication
  # custom fields
  field_special:
    plugin: static_map
    source: special
    map:
      1: 1
      2: 2
      3: 3
```

I have a `field_special` as taxonomy term reference field in the node I want to migrate to.

How can I map the source field to be used in the destination field which is a taxonomy term reference field?

I'm using Drupal 8.1.2 with migrate_plus migrate_tools migrate_drupal enabled.

Comment: Can you add snippets to sample data you are using?

Comment: And are you using Drupal 8.1 or 8.0 (or 8.2)?

Comment: Also, are you using the migrate_plus module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rewritten my yml to use:

```
field_special:
  plugin: iterator
  source: field_special
  process:
    target_id: tid
```

And written a preparerow function in my class to output an array as source property:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    $nid = $row->getSourceProperty('nid');

    $result = $this->getDatabase()->query(
      'SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(field_special_tid) as tids
      FROM
        {field_data_field_special} fs
      WHERE
        fs.entity_id = :nid
      ',
      array(':nid' => $nid)
    );
    foreach ($result as $record) {
      if (!is_null($record->tids)) {
        $row->setSourceProperty('special', explode(',', $record->tids));
      }
    }
    return parent::prepareRow($row);
  }
```

This workaround will do for now, but if you have a better answer please post so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Your solution seems the way to go. The only issue is the format in which you queried the database.

Comment: The query works, Tough it could be nicer but since it's a migration script I didn't care to use a entity field query.